# How to control the font kerning for Canvas fillText() in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, fonts, kerning

I'm trying to create a decent cross-browser rendering engine of canvas text. I have noticed that kerning pairs don't render properly in Chrome, but in Safari and Firefox they work fine.

*Chrome:*

[image]

*Firefox:*

[image]

*Safari:*

[image]

Try the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/o1n5014u/

*Code sample:*

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "40px Arial";
ctx.fillText("VAVA Te", 10, 50);
```

Does anyone have any workaround? I have looked for bug reports, but I can't find anything.

Comment: BTW, it’s the same  for SVG but then we have `font-kerning: normal;` that solves it. I wish we had the same for Canvas...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [W3 CSS3 Fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-kerning-prop):

To explicitly turn on the [`font-kerning`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-kerning-prop) you need to set the `font-kerning` property to `normal`,

```
canvas{
    font-kerning : normal;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman/o1n5014u/1/)

Based on this article on [Cross-browser kerning pairs & ligatures](http://aestheticallyloyal.com/public/optimize-legibility),  Alternatively you can use the `optimizeLegibility` like this,

```
canvas{
     text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman/o1n5014u/2/)

> The declaration is currently supported by: Safari 5, The Webkit
>   Nightlies & Chrome.
>
> Firefox already uses optimizeLegibility by default for text sizes
>   above 20px.

Comment: I had no idea you could add typographic CSS styles to a `canvas` element. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not much of a help, but we had this same issue with a text processor application that is running in a browser.

We tried the following canvas settings that don't work:

- [canvas.style.fontKerning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning) (settings this to `none` should disable kerning, but it does not work)
- [canvas.style.textRendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering) (settings this to `optimizeSpeed` should disable kerning, but it does not work)
- [canvas.style.letterSpacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing) (settings this to `0` should disable kerning, but it does not work)

Our solution is to prevent the kerning from happening, by drawing each "letter" one-by-one after each other onto the canvas. For this however you need to calculate the glyph widths using the font metrics from the font file.

Comment: Note that these features seem to work now in Chrome 83, and that drawing chars letter by letter has a host of gotchas to be aware of, especially in foreign languages.